# c# service renaming files!

Tags: c#, windows-services, renaming

I have a windows service , that takes files with metadata(FIDEF) and corresponding video file and , translates the XML(FIDEF) using XSLT .

I get the file directory listing for FIDEF's and if a video file of the same name exists it translates it. That works ok , but it is on a timer to search every minute. I am trying to handle situations where the same file name enters the input directory but is already in the output directory. I just have it changing the output name to (copy) thus if another file enters i should get (copy)(copy).mov  but the service won't start with filenames of the same directory already in the output , it works once and then does not seem to pick up any new files.

Any Help would be great as I have tried a few things with no good results. I believe its the renaming methods, but I've put most of the code up in case its a clean up issue or something else. 
(forgive some of the names just trying different things).

```
    private void getFileList()
    {
        //Get FILE LIST FROM Directory
        try
        {
            // Process Each String/File In Directory
            string result;
            //string filename;
             filepaths = null;
             filepaths = Directory.GetFiles(path, Filetype);

            foreach (string s in filepaths)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < filepaths.Length; i++)
                {
                    //Result Returns Video Name
                    result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepaths[i]);
                    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(filepaths[i]);

                    PreformTranslation(f, outputPath + result , result);


                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Error " + e);
        }


    }

    private void MoveVideoFiles(String Input, String Output)
    {
        File.Move(Input, Output);

    }
    private string GetUniqueName(string name)
    {


         //Original Filename
        String ValidName = name;
        //remove FIDEF from filename
        String Justname1 = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name);
        //get .mov extension 
        String Extension2 = Path.GetExtension(Justname1);
        //get filename with NO extensions
        String Justname = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Justname1);
        //get .Fidef
        String Extension = Path.GetExtension(name);
        int cnt = 0;

        //string[] FileName = Justname.Split('(');
        //string Name = FileName[0];

        while (File.Exists(ValidName)==true)
        {
            ValidName = outputPath + Justname + "(Copy)" + Extension2 + Extension;
            cnt++;

        }
        return ValidName;
    }
    private string getMovFile(string name)
    {
        String ValidName = name;
        String Ext = Path.GetExtension(name);
        String JustName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name);

        while(File.Exists(ValidName))
        {
            ValidName = outputPath + JustName + "(Copy)" + Ext;
        }
        return ValidName;
    }



    //Preforms the translation requires XSL & FIDEF name.
    private void PreformTranslation(FileInfo FileName, String OutputFileName , String result)
    {

        string FidefName = OutputFileName + ".FIDEF";
        String CopyName;
        String copyVidName = outputPath + result;

            XslCompiledTransform myXslTransform;
            myXslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
            try
            {
                myXslTransform.Load(XSLname);

            }
            catch 
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Error in loading XSL");
            }
            try
            {   //only process FIDEF's with corresponding Video file
                if (AllFidef == "no")
                {
                    //Check if video exists if yes,
                    if (File.Exists(path + result))
                    {
                        //Check for FIDEF File Already Existing in the Output Directory. 
                        if (File.Exists(FidefName))
                        {
                            //Get unique name
                            CopyName = GetUniqueName(FidefName);
                            copyVidName= getMovFile(copyVidName);


                            //Translate and create new FIDEF. 

                            //double checking the file is here
                            if (File.Exists(outputPath + result))
                            {
                                myXslTransform.Transform(FileName.ToString(), CopyName);
                                File.Delete(FileName.ToString());
                                MoveVideoFiles(path + result, copyVidName);

                            }
                            ////Move Video file with Corresponding Name. 

                        }


                        else
                        {  //If no duplicate file exsists in Directory just move. 
                            myXslTransform.Transform(FileName.ToString(), OutputFileName + ".FIDEF");
                            MoveVideoFiles(path + result, outputPath + result);
                        }
                    }

                    }
                else
                {
                    //Must have FIDEF extension
                    //Processes All FIDEFS and moves any video files if found. 
                    myXslTransform.Transform(FileName.ToString(), OutputFileName + ".FIDEF"); 
                    if (File.Exists(path + result))
                    {
                        MoveVideoFiles(path + result, outputPath + result);
                    }


                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Error Transforming " + "FILENAME = " + FileName.ToString()
                    + " OUTPUT_FILENAME = " + OutputFileName + "\r\n" +"\r\n"+  e);

            }

        }
```

Comment: Why do you have the inner `for` loop? It essentially duplicates the `foreach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot wrong with your code. `getFileList` has the unneeded inner `for` loop for starters. Get rid of it. Your `foreach` loop has `s`, which can replace `filepaths[i]` from your `for` loop. Also, don't do `outputPath + result` to make file paths. Use `Path.Combine(outputPath, result)` instead, since `Path.Combine` handles directory characters for you. Also, you need to come up with a better name for `getFileList`, since that is not what the method does at all. Do not make your method names liars.

I would simply get rid of `MoveVideoFiles`. The compiler just might too.

`GetUniqueName` only works if your file name is of the form `name.mov.fidef`, which I'm assuming it is. You really need better variable names though, otherwise it will be a maintenance nightware later on. I would get rid of the `== true` in the `while` loop condition, but that is optional. The assignment inside the `while` is why your files get overwritten. You always generate the same name (`something(Copy).mov.fidef`), and as far as I can see, if the file exists, I think you blow the stack looping forever. You need to fix that loop to generate a new name (and don't forget `Path.Combine`). Maybe something like this (note this is untested):

```
int copyCount = 0;
while (File.Exists(ValidName))
{
    const string CopyName = "(Copy)";
    string copyString = copyCount == 0 ? CopyName : (CopyName + "(" + copyCount + ")");
    string tempName = Justname + copyString + Extension2 + Extension;
    ValidName = Path.Combine(outputPath, tempName);
    copyCount++;
}
```

This generates `something(Copy).mov.fidef` for the first copy, `something(Copy)(2).mov.fidef` for the second, and so on. Maybe not what you want, but you can make adjustments.

At this point you have a lot to do. `getMovFile` looks as though it could use work in the same manner as `GetUniqueName`. You'll figure it out. Good luck.

Comment: Yep your code works great! (added copyString to tempName), Thanks for the help with the changes and tips!. Really great help , should be trying not to learn bad habits. :)